# Simple account system

Tags: java

I have been working on this small accounting thing, having some problems with the withdrawal section. I need help.

```
public class Account {

private double balance;

public Account (double initialBalance){
    if(initialBalance > 0){
        balance = initialBalance;
    }
}

public double getDeposit(){
    return balance;

}
public void credit (double amount){
    balance += amount;
}
public double withdraw(double amount2){

    //double amount1;
    //double with;
    if (balance > initialBalance){
        balance - amount2;
    }
```

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: If this is homework please tag it so. Can you be a little more specific about the problem you have?

Comment: I would not call the argument `amount2`; just call it `amount`. Names should convey meaning, and the `2` is not meaningful.

Comment: My problem is with the'withdraw' method, it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 4):

You need to do this in `withdraw()`:

```
balance = balance - amount2;
```

Or this (it's equivalent):

```
balance -= amount2;
```

Otherwise, you won't be updating the value of the balance

Answer (score 0):

What's your problem?
in the withdraw function shouldn't have you written:

```
public double withdraw(double amount2){

  if(amount2>0 && balance-amount2>0 /* or min acceptable deposit */){

     balance-=amount2;

   }
}
```